# Accessing the cakePHP hashed passwords from PHP service

Tags: php, cakephp, passwords, cakephp-2.0

We have a few applications that make use of the same database. The user passwords are hashed by cakePHP application. What we would like to do is to compare the passwords hashed by php service and the ones hashed by cakePHP.

Is there a PHP function that would imitate the hashing of CakePHP in order to compare the passwords? If not, what would be the easiest way to go around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe CakePHP uses the function `hash` inside `lib\Cake\Utility\Security.php` to get the hashed data of the user and compare it with the hash stored in the password field:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L107

I also would say that it usually uses the `sha1` function of PHP by default which uses the user's `password` and the `Security.salt` value (defined in core.php) as the input string.
Therefor, you could do something like this to get the value saved on the `password` field of the `users` table:

```
sha1('cce93fda02c7f3ebf1g46c583589f1fd257e9d5d'. 'mypassword');
```

This is the full function in CakePHP which makes uses of `sha1`:

```
public static function hash($string, $type = null, $salt = false) {
    if (empty($type)) {
        $type = self::$hashType;
    }
    $type = strtolower($type);

    if ($type === 'blowfish') {
        return self::_crypt($string, $salt);
    }
    if ($salt) {
        if (!is_string($salt)) {
            $salt = Configure::read('Security.salt');
        }
        $string = $salt . $string;
    }

    if (!$type || $type === 'sha1') {
        if (function_exists('sha1')) {
            return sha1($string);
        }
        $type = 'sha256';
    }

    if ($type === 'sha256' && function_exists('mhash')) {
        return bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $string));
    }

    if (function_exists('hash')) {
        return hash($type, $string);
    }
    return md5($string);
}
```

You can read more about it in [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security%3a%3ahash).